How to add custom Azure Blob Storage metadata to an index created by AzureOpenAI - Chat with your data
I have documents in Azure Blob Storage, which I would like to use to ground the responses of a GPT-4 model deployed in AzureOpenAI Studio. I have assigned to some of those documents in Blob Storage a metadata tag, called data_quality.
My idea is that the index that AzureOpenAI - Chat with your data queries should preferentially pull the content from documents whose data_quality is set to a high value, e.g. Gold, or otherwise fall back on lower quality data (e.g., Silver, Under approval etc).
My issue is that, when I add a custom field named data_quality to the index and then use Azure AI Search Explorer, the field always appear as null for all documents, even those that do have a value set.
How do I successfully map the metadata tag on Azure Blob Storage to the corresponding field? Also, once this index is created, will I have to connect a new instance of the AzureOpenAI chat to this Azure AI Search index, or recreate everything via connection to Blob Storage?

Update: I was able to solve via the following link. However, when the time came to connect AzureOpenAI on my data, it still forced me to map pre-configured fields (content, filepath, title, url) and didn't give me an option to add data_quality. Does this mean that any custom-field added to the index will be ignored? When chatting with the model, it is clearly oblivious to data quality.

what is the data type of your field data_quality?

Provided solution below. check if it working or not. @SteP

If you added the metadata tag for existing data and index you need to run the indexer again.

If you still getting null values, try creating new index with metadata tags are added in storage.
Next, in openai after selecting you index while adding data source you check mark Use Custom field mapping and click next.

Now, you can select your fields.
Select data_quality in Content data so that when you query on data quality it gives results accordingly.

Here, my metadata is ragstatus.

Also, make sure data_quality field is of type string, because only string fields you can configure in field mappings.

Thank you, but the model still seems to be oblivious to data_quality, stating that it can't find information in the data.

are you still getting null for data_quality field?
